# Java - listen when an exception is caught in an external class

Tags: java, logging, exception, log4j

Is there a way to create a listener in a separate class that runs a certain piece of code whenever an exception is caught within your project?

My code has a lot of try-catches in it, and if an exception is caught I would like to see the logs using log4j. I can do the following for every try-catch I have fairly easily (just with some time effort):

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Example.class);

public void testMethod() {
    try {
        // some code here that could throw an exception
    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error("Unexpected error has occurred: ", e);
    }
}
```

This will log the exception using log4j. However, I would need to do that over 50 times, and it's so redundant that I would rather be able to use 1 method to do that. So, is there a way to instead do something like this?

```
public class ListenerClass {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ListenerClass.class);

    // This method will be listening for exceptions to be caught within the project
    /**
     * @param e - The exception that was just caught
    */
    public void listenerMethod(ExceptionCaught e) {
        logger.error("An exception has been thrown: ", e);
    }

}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Generally you have explicit logging for normal expected situations, and a catch-all logging functionality when something unexpected happens. However it's not clear from your first example whether you're catching `Exception` because it's necessary, or because you don't want to write proper exception handling. Which one is it? For the first one setting the default handler can be useful.

Comment: In my code, which unfortunately I can't share, I catch several exceptions which I throw on purpose if something is wrong. I have some code that runs specific to that each exception in the catch block. My issue is that I want a generic exception listener, so that whenever one of these exceptions is caught, it will run my custom logic AND the listener will be triggered and it will run my logging code. Does that clarify it a bit?

Comment: But if you're already catching the exception why can't you log it right there? You're not gaining anything from offloading it to a central place, it's only useful for the exceptions you *don't* catch. If you're catching them, you have the most information right at the catch site.

Comment: I have my current implementation doing that. Like I said, with 50+ try-catch blocks it's just a bit annoying to replicate code like this. If I can centralize it, it makes future upkeep much easier

Comment: If you get an exception and you catch it, you log it there and then. That's standard protocol. Notice the word "uncaught" in `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`? There are some exceptions (heh) of course. With Spring's exception handler mechanism you might map certain exceptions directly to HTTP error codes, but in general logging is something you need to spend effort on. If you end up writing the same exact code over and over again, perhaps you're logging on a too low level and you have a design issue.

Comment: Consider altering your design:  remove all the try/catch blocks, and instead add `throws MyCustomException` (or whatever the exception actually is) to each method’s signature.  (*Do not* write `throws Exception` under any circumstances;  things like NullPointerExceptions are bugs in your code and should not be caught, they should be permitted to cause a failure so you will be motivated to fix them.)

Comment: A comment unrelated to your logging question: having lots of try-catch blocks is a code smell. Well-designed code typically has very few try-catch blocks.

Answer (score 3):

Standard [java](/questions/tagged/java) way:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler( (thread, throwable) -> {
        log(throwable.getMessage(), thread.getId());
});
```

which will handle uncaught `RuntimeException`s, and unless otherwise specified it will act for all your application threads.

Just remember the Exceptions are thrown for a reason, and shouldn't be ignored, especially `RuntimeException`s.

---

If you are using an older version of `java` (before 8), you must explicitly instantiate an anonymous class:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
      @Override
      public void uncaughtException(final Thread t, final Throwable e) {

      }
});
```

Comment: It's not "`RuntimeExceptions` as well". Checked exceptions can't be handled by this, because you can't let a checked exception be uncaught. So it's **only** `RuntimeExceptions` that will be handled by the uncaught exception handler.

Comment: @Kayaman objects instantiated by reflections or an injection framework that throw a checked exception during construction may be uncaught. But I do agree I should write << which will handle [the case just mentioned] as well >>, as its a far more specific case than `RuntimeException`s. And the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` is primarily meant for RE's.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()